# Error while using DataBind in RowDatabound vb.net GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Please see below code. I am trying to populate dropdown list while edit in a GridView control.

```
 Private Function GetSiteSelection() As DataTableReader

    ''' some code to return DataTableReader

End Function

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewAttachedStation.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim dtrSiteSel As Data.DataTableReader = Nothing

        If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then

            Dim SiteName As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListType"), DropDownList)

            SiteName.DataSource = GetSiteSelection()
            SiteName.DataTextField = "CODE_NAME"
            SiteName.DataValueField = "CODE_ID"
            SiteName.DataBind() <-- Error is here

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Getting error at SiteName.DataBind()

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Mockup as requestred: This works for simple text box, but not for dropdown. I referred other sources, but most of them are using the same way - which is not working.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Width="100%"
            CellPadding="0"
            BorderStyle="None"
            AllowSorting="true"
            OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tblAtlData"></AlternatingRowStyle>
            <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="tblData"></RowStyle>
            <FooterStyle CssClass="tblHeader"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="BlueViolet" CssClass="tblData"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblHeader" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EDIT">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="EditLinkButton" Text="Edit" Font-Bold="true" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("STATION ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="5%" />
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateLinkButton" Text="Update" Font-Bold="true" CommandName="Update" runat="server"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("STATION ID") %>' />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelLinkButton" Text="Cancel" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"  OnClick="OnCancel" />

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Selection Type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSiteSelection" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Site") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" CssClass="GeneralText" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="10%" /> 
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListTypeNameRow" CssClass="GeneralText"
                        onkeydown="typeAhead()" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField='<%# Eval("SiteSelectionType") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show markups of both `DropDownList` & `GridView`? Possibly you're using `Bind` or `Eval` in incorrect way, such like adding conditional blocks/statements which doesn't support data binding.

Comment: added. Thank you in advance. Please let me know if you have any other reference.

Comment: Try something like this: `<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListTypeNameRow" ... DataTextField='<%# CStr(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteSelectionType")) %>' />`. Possibly `DataTextField` property doesn't support data binding with direct `Eval()`.

Comment: No luck. shows blank dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete the condition

```
If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you trying to use `DataBinder.Eval` method in a property which doesn't support data-binding.

This `DropDownList` setup should be work for solve the issue:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListTypeNameRow" CssClass="GeneralText"
                  onkeydown="typeAhead()" AutoPostBack="true"
                  DataTextField="CODE_NAME" DataValueField="CODE_ID"
                  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SiteSelectionType") %>' />
```

Since [`DataTextField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx) property is already set to a column/field name in code-behind, you should also set it into the markup with the same name, i.e. `CODE_NAME`.

If you want to display default selected value in each dropdown for corresponding row, the `Eval` part should be placed in [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead.

Comment: nope, that did not work too. Further, I believe that we have to perform binding in code-behind. Are you suggesting to make some code behind change? if so please show me.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net GridView with DropDownList in ItemTemplate of TemplateField.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="ContactName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT ContactName, Country FROM Customers")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetData(query As String) As DataSet
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.Connection = con
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            Using ds As New DataSet()
                sda.Fill(ds)
                Return ds
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

       'Find the DropDownList in the Row.
        Dim ddlCountries As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountries"), DropDownList)
        ddlCountries.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Customers")
        ddlCountries.DataTextField = "Country"
        ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Country"
        ddlCountries.DataBind()

        'Add Default Item in the DropDownList.
        ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select"))

        'Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList.
        Dim country As String = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry"), Label).Text
        ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```